# jQuery change width of img on resize works but not on maximize

Tags: jquery

Edit/Solved: Reason was I did not set the width for the case of the window being wider than 1268 which does not matter on smooth resizing but does if you jump to a higher value than 1268 by maximizing.

---

If I manually resize the window the affected divs (.bannerbild, .banner) resize as well. Unfortunately they don't do that on maximizing the window.

The #dimension div displays the correct width and height on manual resizing and maximizing.

I tested this in the recent versions of Chrome, IE, FF and Opera.

Edit: I have to rephrase a bit: If the window is maximized and then gets "unmaximized" then the divs do indeed resize. (they don't resize to the max width though when I hit the maximize button again ...)

```
var slideamount; 

function dim() {
    var width = $( window ).width();
    var height = $( window ).height();
    $("#dimensions").html(width + " x " + height);

    if ($( window ).width() <= 1268){
        $(".bannerbild").css({"width":$( window ).width()});
        $(".banner").css({"width":$( window ).width()});
        $("#main").css({"width":$( window ).width()});
    }   

    if($( window ).width() <= 1268) {
        slideamount = "-=" + ($( window ).width());
        return slideamount;
    }
    else {
        slideamount = "-=1268px"
        return slideamount;
    }           
}

dim();

$( window ).resize(function() {
    dim();  
});
```

Comment: That means ur `dim()` is not called on resize.

Comment: WIll be nice if u create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Anup Yes dim() is called because the #dimensions are correct and also dim() is called on all the manual resizing (click-hold-resizing). I will set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resizing the divs once the screen width goes back to greater than 1268px. You are only resizing the divs when it goes smaller. I am not sure what your original width of the divs are but just replace the values in the code below with the proper ones.

Try this:

```
var slideamount; 

function dim() {
    var width = $( window ).width();
    var height = $( window ).height();
    $("#dimensions").html(width + " x " + height);

    if ($( window ).width() <= 1268){
        $(".bannerbild").css({"width":$( window ).width()});
        $(".banner").css({"width":$( window ).width()});
        $("#main").css({"width":$( window ).width()});
    }
    else {

        // Set this how ever you like for your original width
        var originalWidth = "1000px"; 

        // Set the widths of the divs back to their original values that you set
        $(".bannerbild").css({"width": originalWidth);
        $(".banner").css({"width": originalWidth);
        $("#main").css({"width": originalWidth);
    }   

    if($( window ).width() <= 1268) {
        slideamount = "-=" + ($( window ).width());
        return slideamount;
    }
    else {
        slideamount = "-=1268px"
        return slideamount;
    }           
}

dim();

$( window ).resize(function() {
        dim();  
});
```

Comment: If that was the case, why does it manually resize correctly (it gets bigger too, not just smaller)?

Comment: If you provide a jsfiddle I could look at the more. Since there is no HTML I cannot say for sure.

Comment: It is okay, It works if I add your 3 lines. I am just not getting why the divs would resize correctly on manual resizing then ... actually I do, because it would resize the whole time while it is under 1268 but not once it gets over 1268, which happens when I maximize from let's say 675 to 1900. Thanks @tokyovariable

Comment: Your conditional of the if statement will only be true up until the screen is bigger than 1268px. After that the conditional does not hold true anymore, so therefore it is never called. That would be why if you maximize the screen and its bigger than 1268px the conditional will be fired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
   dim();
});
```

---

Pull out the variable declaration outside the function and use that variables inside the function like this:

```
var slideamount; 
var $width = $( window ).width();
var $height = $( window ).height();
function dim() {

    $("#dimensions").html(width + " x " + height);

    if ($width <= 1268){
        $(".bannerbild, .banner, #main").css({"width":$width});
    }   

    if($width <= 1268) {
        slideamount = "-=" + $width;
        return slideamount;
    }
    else {
        slideamount = "-=1268px"
        return slideamount;
    }           
}

dim();

$( window ).on('load ready',function() {
    dim();  
});
```

Comment: That does not seem to help.

Comment: If I copy that code the divs do not display. If I only pull out the variables and leave the rest as is, it displays the div but not the correct #dimensions which leads me to believe, that the vars outside of the function are not passed to the function.